# Как метод filter работает с includes в этом коде?

Tags: javascript

Дан массив числами, например: [10, 20, 30, 50, 235, 3000].
Выведите на экран только те числа из массива, которые
начинаются на цифру 1, 2 или 5.

Нашел такое решение

```js
let arr = [10, 20, 30, 50, 235, 3000];
 
console.log(arr.filter(num => ['1','2','5'].includes(num.toString()[0])))
```

Никак не могу до конца понять, как работает этот код. Для чего нужно num.toString() и можно ли сделать с помощью startWith или же этот метод работает только со строкой?

Comment: А если подебажить?

Comment: очевидно же, что цифру превращаешь в стринг и берешь первый символ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для каждого `num` из массива `arr`

1. число переводится в строку `num.toString()`
2. берется его первая цифра `[0]`
3. проверяется наличие этой цифры в массиве `['1','2','5']`
4. если `includes` возвращает `true` - число отправляет в итоговый массив